# Angular JS ng-repeat not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a controller like this:

```
controller('BreadCrumbs', ['$scope','crumble','$rootScope', function ($scope,crumble,$rootScope) {    
    function init (){
        $scope.ui={};
        $scope.ui.mdBreadCrumbs=[{"path":"path1","label":"label1"}];     
        $rootScope.oldScope=$scope;
    }
    $scope.setBreadCrumbs=function() {        
        $scope.ui.mdBreadCrumbs=crumble.trail;    
    } 
    init();
}]);
```

and in HTML,

```
<ol id="breadCrumbList"  ng-controller="BreadCrumbs as bcrmbs">
 {{ui.mdBreadCrumbs}}
  <li ng-repeat="bc in ui.mdBreadCrumbs">
    <a ng-href="{{bc.path}}">{{bc.label}}</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

`{{ui.mdBreadCrumbs}}` is showing some like `[{"path":"path1","label":"label1"}]`.
But in ng-repeat, it is not iterating.
Using `$scope.setBreadCrumbs` I put some more values, but still ngRepeat not working.

Anyone have any idea why it is not working?

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: Try changing `ng-controller="BreadCrumbs as bcrmbs"` to `ng-controller="BreadCrumbs"`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<ol id="breadCrumbList"  ng-controller="BreadCrumbs as bcrmbs">
```

to

```
<ol id="breadCrumbList"  ng-controller="BreadCrumbs">
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('BreadCrumbs', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.ui = {};
  $scope.ui.mdBreadCrumbs = [{
    "path": "path1",
    "label": "label1"
  }];
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="BreadCrumbs">
  <ol id="breadCrumbList">
 {{ui.mdBreadCrumbs}}
  <li ng-repeat="bc in ui.mdBreadCrumbs">
    <a ng-href="{{bc.path}}">{{bc.label}}</a>
  </li>
</ol>
  <script type=" text/javascript " src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.js "></script>
  <script type="text/javascript " src="MainViewController.js "></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change something in your HTML and your HTML should be like this:

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="BreadCrumbs">
      <div ng-repeat="bc in ui.mdBreadCrumbs">
          <a ng-href="{{bc.path}}">{{bc.label}}</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```